# Java does not handle softlinks correctly on Windows XP

Tags: java, windows

```
new File(path_to_softlink).getCanonicalPath()
```

Does not return the place where softlinks points to but `path_to_softlink`. Support for symbolic links is enabled with http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/ln/ln.html#symboliclinksforwindowsxp

---

```
System.out.println(Files.readSymbolicLink(Paths.get(path).toRealPath()));

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: symbolic links not supported
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readSymbolicLink(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:617)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readSymbolicLink(Files.java:1432)
    at file.CheckFreeSpace.main(CheckFreeSpace.java:18)



System.out.println(Files.isSymbolicLink(Paths.get(path).toRealPath()));

false
```

Doesn't Java work with symlinks on XP?

Comment: Have a look in the [Oracle Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html#read) probably this solve your problem.

Comment: @SubOptimal Yeah, would you provide code or tell why my code doesn't work?

Comment: What about taking the example from the tutorial? Isn't it short and verbose enough?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you try to read the link from the link target `Files.readSymbolicLink(Paths.get(path).toRealPath())`.

The following code worked on a Windows 7 machine.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

class SoftLinkDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Path softLink = Paths.get("d:/softLink");
        Path linkTarget = Paths.get("d:/linkTarget");
        Files.deleteIfExists(softLink);
        Files.deleteIfExists(linkTarget);
        Files.createFile(linkTarget);
        Files.createSymbolicLink(softLink, linkTarget);
        System.out.println("linkTarget: " + linkTarget);
        System.out.println("softLink  : " + softLink);
        System.out.println("Files.isSymbolicLink(softLink)  : " + Files.isSymbolicLink(softLink));
        System.out.println("softLink.toRealPath()           : " + softLink.toRealPath());
        System.out.println("Files.readSymbolicLink(softLink): " + Files.readSymbolicLink(softLink));
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
linkTarget: d:\linkTarget
softLink  : d:\softLink
Files.isSymbolicLink(softLink)  : true
softLink.toRealPath()           : D:\linkTarget
Files.readSymbolicLink(softLink): d:\linkTarget
```

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Symbolic links not supported on this operating system
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createSymbolicLink(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:529)
 at java.nio.file.Files.createSymbolicLink(Files.java:1043)
 at file.SoftLink.main(SoftLink.java:15)` (line with `Files.createSymbolicLink(softLink, linkTarget);`) ;(

Comment: @SmitJohnth Maybe you could give this quik'n'dirty "workaround" a try. Put as first line in `main(String[] args)` this one `System.setProperty("os.version", "6.1");`.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Should not get here
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.CreateSymbolicLink0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.CreateSymbolicLink(WindowsNativeDispatcher.java:890)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createSymbolicLink(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:578)
 at java.nio.file.Files.createSymbolicLink(Files.java:1043)
 at file.SoftLink.main(SoftLink.java:17)` (`Files.createSymbolicLink(softLink, linkTarget);`)

Comment: @SmitJohnth Which Java version have you used?

Comment: @SmitJohnth I will check. Why it's working on that Win XP PC (have no own access to it).

Comment: @SmitJohnth I have to revoke my comment about WinXP. The PC on which the snippet was tested wasn't running WinXP. Sorry for that confusioin. As I have no access to a machine running WinXP I cannot investigate further. Maybe it's possible to instrument the driver you have mentioned via JNI/JNA. (assuming that with the driver you're able to use symlinks on WinXP)